# How to do full outer join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, full-outer-join

I have two tables

```
t1(id,c)
values = (1,aa),(2,bb),(3,cc)

t2(id,c)
values = (2,bbb),(3,ccc),(4,ddd)
```

I need a query that will produce:

```
1,aa,null,null
2,bb,2,bbb
3,cc,3,ccc
null,null,4,ddd
```

Can this be done in MySql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.id,t1.c, t2.id, t2.c
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.id=t2.id
UNION
select t1.id,t1.c, t2.id, t2.c
FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t1 on t1.id=t2.id
```

based on albin's response.

Answer (score 2):

It is called a full outer join, but http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html says it is not supported in MySQL, but that you can emulate with a UNION.

Search for "Full outer join" on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an outer join. MySQL doesn't support this directly.

However, [here's](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/) a blog describing how to do a `full outer join` in MySQL.